# data.put() throws IndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: for-loop, dictionary, indexoutofboundsexception, treemap

So i have this code to input an order and a price for a specified number of items
public class SetMenu0 {

```
private double price;
private int size;
private String output;
private String priceOutput;

ArrayList orderList = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList priceList = new ArrayList<Double>();

public SetMenu0()
{
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter New Order?(Y)(N): ");
    String init = input.nextLine();

    if(init.equalsIgnoreCase("y"))
    {
        System.out.print("Enter Number of Orders: ");
        size = input.nextInt();

        for(int i = 0; i<=size; i++)
        {
            i++;
            System.out.print("Enter Order: ");
            orderList.add(input.next());
            System.out.print("Enter Price: ");
            priceList.add(input.nextDouble());
        }
    }
}

public ArrayList getOrd()
{
    return orderList;
}

public ArrayList getPri()
{
    return priceList;
}

public int getSize()
{
    return size;
}
```

}

Now when i use it with the TreeMap i get an indexOutOfBoundsException here
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        //blank workbook
        XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();

```
    //create blank sheet
    XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("Food");

    SetMenu0 set = new SetMenu0();

    ArrayList orderList = set.getOrd();
    ArrayList priceList = set.getPri();

    int size = orderList.size();
    Map<String, Object[]> data = new TreeMap<String, Object[]>();
    data.put("1", new Object[]{"Order", "Price"});
    try{
    for(int i=0; i<size; i++)
    {
        int in = i+2;
        String lineNum = ""+in;
        data.put(lineNum, new Object[]{orderList.get(i), priceList.get(i)});
    }
    }
    catch(IndexOutOfBoundsException e)
    {
        System.out.print("problem");
    }
```

The exception happens when set the size to 3 upwards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem might be in this bit:

```
for(int i = 0; i<=size; i++)
    {
        i++;
        System.out.print("Enter Order: ");
        orderList.add(input.next());
        System.out.print("Enter Price: ");
        priceList.add(input.nextDouble());
    }
```

Try removing the i++ from loop body.

Comment: hahaha. thanks so much. that has bugged me for a while, so silly